# How to convert a akka.stream.javadsl.Source to java.util.concurrent.Flow.Publisher

Tags: akka-stream, java.util.concurrent, reactive-streams

I'm experimenting with the `Test Compatability Kit (tck)` for reactive Streams, and having tested a few Publishers myself, I wanted to test an `akka Source`. But in order to do so I need to convert a Source (or Source + Processor(s)) to a `java.util.concurrent.Flow.Publisher`.

```
@Override
public Flow.Publisher<Integer> createFlowPublisher(long elements) {
    return new FlowPublisher((int) elements);  // <-- how to test an akka.Source?
}

class FlowPublisher implements java.util.concurrent.Flow.Publisher {
    ...
```

And I can't find anywhere how to do this.

Is there somehwere some documentation on this, or does someone know the answer by heart?

Answer (score 1):

you can convert akka-streams `Source` to `org.reactivestreams.Publisher` (which is the same as `java.util.concurrent.Flow` according to [reactive-streams](https://www.reactive-streams.org/)):

```
implicit val sys: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val source = Source.single(1) // some random source
val publisher: Publisher[Int] = source.runWith(Sink.asPublisher(false))
```

you can find details in the official akka-streams docs - [Integrating with Reactive Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-integrations.html#integrating-with-reactive-streams)

---

the thing to note is that akka-streams has documention and some kits for testing its' component - [Testing streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-testkit.html). i would say that it's better to test akka-streams components with akka-streams testing kit, because you don't need to make additional conversions to `org.reactivestreams.*` entities and the testing code will be much cleaner, simpler and reliable